# How to set STDIN string to specif characters?

Tags: c, string, char, cstring, arrays

How to set input string array to accept only specific letters from STDIN??

```
char arr[testcases][100];
    for(i=0;i<testcases;i++){
    scanf("%99s",&arr[i]);
}
```

I am going to store only letters **a,b,c,d** in my array. How can I restrict other letters from getting stored in my array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
 scanf("%99[a-d]", arr);
```

The return value will be `1` if any initial part of the string matches; input will stop at the first non-matching character.